# Capybara and Rspec not scoping

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec2

I have the model `Price` with the following scopes and attributes.

```
def self.total
  self.sum(:amount) + self.sum(:tax)
end

def self.today
  where(:date => Date.today)
end

def self.for_data
  where(:bought => true)
end
```

I have the scope chain that gets the current users total amount of today.

```
<p class="today">
  Today
   <span class="amount today">
     <%= number_to_currency(current_user.prices.for_data.today.total) %>
   </span>
</p>
```

I write a spec to test this.

```
# user_pages_spec

describe 'Overview Page' do
  it 'shows spending' do
     make_user_and_login
     price = FactoryGirl.create(:price)
     click_link('Overview') 
     page.should have_selector('title', :text => 'Overview')
     within('p.today', :text => 'Today') do
       page.should have_content('$1.01')
     end
  end
end
```

This is my Price Factory:

```
factory :price do
  amount '1.00'
  tax '0.01'
  bought true
  date Date.today
end
```

Unfortunately, this returns the error:

```
1) UserPages Account Settings Data Page shows spending
 Failure/Error: page.should have_content('$1.01')
 expected there to be content "$1.01" in "\n\t\t\tToday\n\t\t\t$0.00\n\t\t"
```

Manually placing the `$1.01` in the view works but not when I depend on the scope. It looks like its not detecting the factory or the scope in general as it returns `$0.00`. Why and how is this solved?

Thank you.

---

support/user_macros.rb

```
module UserMacros
  def make_user_and_login
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    visit new_user_session_path
    page.should have_selector('title', :text => 'Login')
    fill_in('Email',    :with => user.email)
    fill_in('Password', :with => user.password)
    click_button('Login')
    page.should have_selector('title', :text => 'Home')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is that price record doesnt have relation with current_user. So current_user total is really 0.00 in this case. You may slove this by changing price factory like this:

```
factory :price do
  amount '1.00'
  tax '0.01'
  bought true
  date Date.today
  user { User.first || FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
end
```

Comment: This didn't do it. Also i'm using Devise if it helps with using `current_user`. I believe your right on having to use the current user though but I'm looking around and can't find anything on doing so.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/3747821 - how about this? Btw, do you use database_cleaner in your tests (what if use User.last instead of .first in price factory)?

Comment: This worked but I also got rid of the `make_user_and_login` method for this test and it also worked. Good alternative though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an integration spec I presume, so you have to perform your seeding steps (Factory creation) before your interactive steps (login).

You can do the following to take care of the user association during factory creation:

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
price = FactoryGirl.create(:price, user: user)
```

Comment: I put in a `before(:each)` block and it still gave me the same error. I also tried to put it before my `make_user_and_login` and logging in.